# Send image data over RTC Data Channel

Tags: javascript, canvas, webrtc

I am trying to send the image data over a `Data Channel`, but it is not working.
When just getting the data from `ctx.getImageData`, I receive a string `"[Object ImageData]"` on the other side. Converting the data piece only to a blob results in an error: `Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': Could not send data`. I get the same error when trying to convert it to an `ArrayBuffer`. How should I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a demo I wrote up just now: http://richard.to/projects/datachannel-demo/

Note that I'm using local channels and am just displaying an image and not rendering onto a canvas. That should be easy to do. You may face issues when actually communicating with a remote device. I haven't tested it out yet. Also it only works in Chrome. But should be straightforward to make work in Firefox.

---

This was a bit tricky to figure out since the WebRTC stuff is constantly changing. Not to mention Firefox and Chrome work slightly differently.

I'm going to focus on Chrome, since the error messages you get seem related to Chrome, specifically `Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': Could not send data`. This issue was described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/U927CZaCdKU

This is due to the `RTP data channel` being rate limited. The link I gave you mentioned `3 KB/sec` and in my testing that sounds about right.

The good news is that after Chrome 31, you can use SCTP based data channels. See here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/y2A97iCByTU.

That means instead of this:

```
window.localPeerConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(servers,
    {optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]});
```

You can do something like this (probably can remove the second parameter):

```
window.localPeerConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(servers,
    {optional: []});
```

I believe you will still be rate limited, but now it is `64kbps`. I may be wrong about this number. Can't find the link I read it from.

One good thing about the SCTP channel is that you can use a reliable data connection (TCP) instead of unreliable (UDP) and the data gets sent in order. I'm not positive about that. Once again, can't find the link.

Now, because of this, it seems you will have to chunk you data still. You can't send it all at the same time in Chrome. You can do that in Firefox though.

The second thing you need to know is that `blob` data is not currently supported by Chrome. At least in regular Chrome 32. This means we have to send data as text if we want to use Chrome.

So what we can do is turn our image data in base64 since `canvas.toDataURL()`. Here is an example of how that would work:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = startimage.width;
canvas.height = startimage.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(startimage, 0, 0, startimage.width, startimage.height);
var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

Now that we have our data, we just need to break up the bas64 string:

Here is an implementation of chunking the data that I use in my demo above:

```
function sendData() {
  trace("Sending data");
  sendButton.disabled = true;
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = startimage.width;
  canvas.height = startimage.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(startimage, 0, 0, startimage.width, startimage.height);

  var delay = 10;
  var charSlice = 10000;
  var terminator = "\n";
  var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  var dataSent = 0;
  var intervalID = 0;

  intervalID = setInterval(function(){
    var slideEndIndex = dataSent + charSlice;
    if (slideEndIndex > data.length) {
      slideEndIndex = data.length;
    }
    sendChannel.send(data.slice(dataSent, slideEndIndex));
    dataSent = slideEndIndex;
    if (dataSent + 1 >= data.length) {
      trace("All data chunks sent.");
      sendChannel.send("\n");
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
  }, delay);
}
```

The implementation is pretty straightforward, basically just using `setInterval`. You can mess around with the slice size and delay parameters. Also we need to set a terminator character to know when are message is finished. I just used a `\n` character.

And here is how the receiver would be implemented. Basically keeps track of the data until it receives the terminator character, which I just used newline character.

```
function handleMessage(event) {
  if (event.data == "\n") {
    endimage.src = imageData;
    trace("Received all data. Setting image.");
  } else {
    imageData += event.data;
    //trace("Data chunk received");
  }
}
```

Hope this helps a bit. It was fun researching it. Not really sure if this would be the ideal solution for sending an image over WebRTC. There are some demos out there that do P2P file transfer and stuff. I guess it depends on your purpose.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am currently doing something completely different (and that's why I forgot about this question). I am currently working with websockets and sending the coordinates of a drawn line for instance, instead of the image. I might still take a look at this to decrease server load, now I know that the data has to be chunked.

Comment: FYI, I can send string on Chrome M40, but always failed when trying to send arraybuffer, I got: "Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': Could not send data"

Answer (score 1):

This exception is caused by exceeding the bandwidth limit agreed upon in the session.

When creating the answer to the offer, you must edit the sessionDescription object that is part of the PeerConnection, to change the `b=AS:` parameter which contains the maximum bandwith in kb/s:

```
var Bandwidth = 5000;
sessionDescription.sdp = sessionDescription.sdp.replace(/b=AS:([0-9]+)/g, 'b=AS:'+Bandwidth+'\r\n');
alert(JSON.stringify(sessionDescription));
```

By default the value is 30kb/s.

Comment: It looks like I am not having this piece of text in my sdp. Maybe when it is not there it is just taking that default value of 30 and  we just need to add it manually to the sdp? And I'd rather have the regex something like this: `/b=AS:([0-9]+)/g`, as I [couldn't get yours to work](http://regexr.com/398og). But if this would work it would be awesome, although it would be even better if the browser itself handles bandwith (just like websockets (I'm not sure but it looks like they do) as I can just throw (massive) ammounts of strings through it without failing).

Comment: Suggested regular expression to replace 30 by 1000 (if that worked...) : var new_offer = offer.replace(/(\Sb=AS:)([0-9]+)(\S)/, "$11000$3");

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a comment bornSwift's answer, but I have not enough reputation to comment. So: when you use an RTP data channel, you will see the Application Specific (AS) bandwidth within the sdp (i.e. b=AS:30). 30 is the default value. You can replace this with an arbitrary value (1638400 works, but if you want to push it further, you will have to trial and error).

However, when you initialize an SCTP data channel, you will not see any AS bandwidth in your sdp. This is just fine. You do not have to worry about it.