# webrtc: failed to send arraybuffer over data channel in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, google-chrome-app, rtcdatachannel

I want to send streaming data (as sequences of `ArrayBuffer`) from a Chrome extension to a Chrome App, since [Chrome message API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) (includes `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, `postMessage`...) does not support `ArrayBuffer` and JS arrays have poor performance, I have to try other methods. Eventually, I found WebRTC over `RTCDataChannel` might a good solution in my case.

I have succeeded to send string over a `RTCDataChannel`, but when I tried to send `ArrayBuffer` I got:

```
code: 19
message: "Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': Could not send data"
name: "NetworkError"
```

It seems that it's not a [bandwidths limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585681/send-image-data-over-rtc-data-channel) problem since it failed even though I sent one byte of data. Here is my code:

```js
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration, { optional: [ { RtpDataChannels: true } ]});
//...
var dataChannel = m.pc.createDataChannel("mydata", {reliable: true});
//...
var ab = new ArrayBuffer(8);
dataChannel.send(ab);
```

Tested on OSX 10.10.1, Chrome M40 (Stnble), M42(Canary); and on Chromebook M40.

I have filed a bug for WebRTC [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4305).

Comment: Ever make any progress on this issue? I'm in a similar boat at the moment. Transferring data via. WebRTC in Chrome using strings is very slow.

Comment: @NickJennings got solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I modified my code, now everything worked amazing:

1. removed `RtpDataChannels` option when creating `RTCPeerConnection`.(YES, remove `RtpDataChannels` option if you want data channel, what a magic world!)
2. on receiver side: no need `createDataChannel`, instead, handle `onmessage`, `onxxx` by using `event.channle` from `pc.ondatachannel` callback:

   ```
   pc.ondatachannel function(event)
       var receiveChannel = event.channel;
       receiveChannel.onmessage = function(event){
           console.log("Got Data Channel Message:", event.data);
       }; 
   };
   ```

Comment: Thanks @lmskull for answering your question, you solved my problem as well.
For anyone that has the same problem: you should not create the same channels on the sender and receiver side, but just use ondatachannel to get the channels created on the other side (works with multiple channels, too). An example here: https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/master/src/content/datachannel/basic/js/main.js